# Creating searchable list using either wild card or data validation

Tags: excel, vba, validation

[image][image]I created POS application using excel with macros
I want to make a dynamic search using the item_name column using "scan Item name" cell E3 provided.
how can i make it a searchable list also?

i tried using data validation from item_name i created but i cant search using it.

** i want to create search list of the item names at E3**
it could be in form of the combo list or data validation using wildcards

**also**
i want to add new code that whenever i search and select a new item name in E3, it also inputs the item ID in E10 and then adds the quantity and price there[image]

**below**
_the macro i used for making any item Id(E10) i type inputs the item name E3,price F6, Quantity F8 automatically, i also want to tweak(i don't know if it's possible) that when i write an accurate item name example 'Apple' it inputs the Item ID, Price and Quantity _

Comment: "searchable list" means: Write something in E3 e.g. \*nana\*, press enter, after open the list in same cell E3 and select a value (from values containing "nana"). You want this? or want another cell eg E2 to write the search criterion and in E3 get the results (in list) ?

Comment: Yes I want to do something like this..how can I go about it? I mean the both of them

Comment: ok I will try to post an answer tomorrow. I will use E2 for the criteria. I will read the products from an area named "PRODUCTS". I will mention the rest of the details tomorrow.

Comment: Here the space is public and does not offer for exchange of e-mail addresses. On the other hand how is it possible to complete this project if you don't understand something relatively simple in relation to the image you posted and the code needed to make it work?

Comment: Oh okay..The code you wrote isn’t what I’m directly having issues with.. I’m going try to add more images

Comment: I have figured it out.. I created a user form in a text box and list search

Answer (score 1):

So I have some code that does the following: The user writes part of a word in E2 and uses * to represent any character or none at all. Then a new list of search results is created. This new list is declared in the Validation of cell E3 with the INDIRECT command, so one can select something from the result. The left cell of E3 is updated with the number of records found. If I leave E2 blank then the list is the same as the original - all products -. This search of the records is done with SQL and for this reason ADODB objects are used... There is a complexity but I don't have anything easier, and I think there will be another "easier" way. In my example everything happens on the same sheet, it will need to be adjusted in your own book. I have also created some "Named ranges" whose names as well as the reference range can be seen in the photo.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private adoConnObj As Object

Public Function openConnection(ByRef wBook As Workbook) As Object
   Dim connection As Object
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   If connection Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("openConnection> Can not create ADODB.Connection")
      Exit Function
   End If
   With connection
      .CursorLocation = 3
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & wBook.Path & "\" & wBook.Name & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
      .Open
   End With
   Set openConnection = connection
End Function

Public Sub closeAdoConn(ByRef adoConn As Object)
   adoConn.Close
   Set adoConn = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      If Target.Address = Me.Range("PROD_CRITERIA").Address Then
         Call whenCritChange(Target.Value2)
      End If
   End If
End Sub

Private Function sqlFindProducts(ByRef adoConn As Object, criteria As String, sourceRng As Range, destination As Range) As Long
   Dim connection As Object, recSet As Object, sql As String, rc As Long, c As Long, swhere As String
   Dim selectA As String, selectB As String, table As String
   
   If sourceRng Is Nothing Or destination Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox ("sqlFindProducts> sourceRng or destination is Nothing")
      Exit Function
   End If
    table = " [" & sourceRng.Worksheet.Name & "$" & sourceRng.Address(0, 0) & "] "
    
   If criteria <> vbNullString Then
      swhere = "WHERE ucase([PRODUCTS]) LIKE " & """" & UCase(criteria) & """"
   End If
   
   sql = "SELECT [PRODUCTS] FROM " & table & swhere & " ORDER BY [PRODUCTS]"
   ' Debug.Print sql
   If adoConn Is Nothing Then
      Set adoConn = openConnection(ThisWorkbook)
      If adoConn Is Nothing Then Exit Function
   End If
   Set recSet = adoConn.Execute(sql)
   sqlFindProducts = recSet.recordCount
   With Me.Range("PROD_ENTRY")
      .ClearContents
      .Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "Items " & recSet.recordCount
   End With
   With destination
      If (.Value2 <> vbNullString) Then
         .Worksheet.Range(.Value2).ClearContents
      End If
      If recSet.recordCount > 0 Then
         Call .Offset(1).CopyFromRecordset(recSet)
         .Value2 = .Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & .Offset(recSet.recordCount).Address(0, 0)
         Me.Range("PROD_ENTRY").Value2 = .Offset(1).Value2
      End If
   End With
   recSet.Close
   Set recSet = Nothing
End Function

Sub whenCritChange(prodCrit As String)
   Dim ln As Long

   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   
   ' HAVE TO READ ABOUT CHARACTER WILDCARDS ( ? , * , _ , % , # , [a] , [!a] , [a-z] , [!a-e] )
   ' for the user convenience, when type *   => we convert it to %
   ' here you can change the criteria as needed
   ' eg. If there are not stars in string and len is <= of 5, then add stars at begining and end
   ln = Len(prodCrit)
   If ln <= 5 And InStr(1, prodCrit, "*") <= 0 Then prodCrit = "*" & prodCrit & "*"
   
   prodCrit = Replace(prodCrit, "%", "[%]")  ' escape % character eg when user writes 13% => 13[%]
   prodCrit = Replace(prodCrit, "*", "%")    ' % means zero or any charactrs
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Call sqlFindProducts(adoConnObj, prodCrit, Me.Range("PRODUCTS"), Me.Range("CUR_PROD_LIST"))
Lerr:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox ("prodCritChange error> " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
   End If
End Sub
```

[image]

The validation of cell E3

[image]

To start working have to change the value of E2, to initialize C1
or write by hand:  C2:C2  in C1

#### A SECOND SOLUTION WITHOUT ADODB AND SQL.

##### The same Named ranges are used

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
      If Target.Address = Me.Range("PROD_CRITERIA").Address Then
         Call createFilteredList(Target.Value2, Me.Range("PRODUCTS"), Me.Range("CUR_PROD_LIST"), Me.Range("PROD_ENTRY"))
      End If
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub createFilteredList(crit As String, source As Range, indrctCell As Range, cellWithValidation As Range)
   Dim r As Range, cnt As Long
   
   Err.Clear
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   With Application
      .Interactive = False
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .EnableEvents = False
   End With
   If crit = vbNullString Then GoTo NoCriteria
   For Each r In source
      If r.Value2 Like crit Then
         cnt = cnt + 1
         indrctCell.Offset(cnt).Value2 = r.Value2
      End If
   Next
   If cnt > 0 Then
      indrctCell.Value2 = indrctCell.Offset(1).Address(0, 0) & ":" & indrctCell.Offset(cnt).Address(0, 0)
      cellWithValidation.Value2 = indrctCell.Offset(1).Value2
   Else
NoCriteria:
      cnt = source.rows.CountLarge - 1
      indrctCell.Value2 = source.Offset(1).Resize(cnt).Address(0, 0)
      cellWithValidation.Value2 = source.Offset(1).Value2
   End If
   cellWithValidation.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = "List " & cnt
Lerr:
   Application.Interactive = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("createValidationList error> " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much..this is really helpful,I will try it tonight and give a feedback

Comment: Hello..I’ve tried this and it isn’t working at all. Is there a way I could send a copy of the excel file I’m working on?

Comment: If you can to upload it someware .... eg dropbox. What is the problem ? what error you get? in whitch line?

Comment: How about an email?.. the code didn’t work at all..probably because I don’t understand it and that’s not the only issue I’m  having..vba is really tough..my email is **oluwasoresamuel@gmail.com**